# onStatusChanged situations

Tags: android, android-gps

I have some doubts regarding `onStatusChanged` from `LocationListener` class.

It know it can present three states: `AVAILABLE`, `TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE` and `OUT_OF_SERVICE`

1. Does `AVAILABLE` gets triggered only when coming out of `TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE`? Or when the GPS has just finished warming-up ? 
   Or right before the first location update?
2. How about `OUT_OF_SERVICE`, when does it get triggered? Right before `onProviderDisabled` ?
3. Is it possible to simulate these events (statuses) with the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

According android source code explanation:

- `OUT_OF_SERVICE` is returned if the provider is   out of service, and this is not expected to change in the near future
- `TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE` is returned if the provider is temporarily    unavailable but is expected to be available shortly
- `AVAILABLE` is returned if the provider is currently available. If extras is    non-null, additional status information may be added to it in the    form of provider-specific key/value pairs.

[LINK](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/location/lib/java/com/android/location/provider/LocationProviderBase.java)